# $u \in$ span$(u_2, \dots, u_p), \dots, u \in$ span$(u_1, \dots, u_{p - 1}) \implies u = 0?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

While trying to solve a problem, I came up with this question.

> Let $E$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space, $2 \le p \le n$ and $\{u_1, \dots, u_p\}$ a set of linearly independent vectors of $E$. If $u \in E$ is such that $u \in$ span$(u_2, u_3, \dots, u_p), u \in$ span$(u_1, u_3, \dots, u_p), \dots, u \in $ span$(u_1, u_2, ..., u_{p - 1})$, is it true that u must be 0?

My approach so far has been trying to use matrices to be able to use its properties. Since for all $i \in \{1, \dots, p\}$ we know that $u \in$ span($u_1, \dots, u_{i - 1}, u_{i + 1}, \dots, u_p)$, then for all $i \in \{1, \dots, p\}$ there exists one and only one set of $\{a_{1, i}, \dots, a_{i - 1, i}, a_{i + 1, i}, \dots, a_{p, i}\}$ such that $u = a_{1, i}u_1 + \cdots + a_{i - 1, i}u_{i - 1} + a_{i + 1, i}u_{i + 1} + \cdots + a_{p, i}u_p$.

In other words, there exists one and only one matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a_{1, 2} &\cdots & \cdots & a_{1, p} \\ a_{2, 1} & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & a_{1, p - 1} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & & \vdots \\ \vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{p, 1} & a_{p, 2} & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

such that
$$\begin{bmatrix} | & & | \\ u_1 & \cdots &u_p \\ | & & | \end{bmatrix} \cdot A = \begin{bmatrix} | & & | \\ u & \cdots &u \\ | & & | \end{bmatrix}$$

Although I have tried to proof this and I have also tried to find a counterexample, nothing I have tried has yield any results so far. Any advice on how to tackle this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $u\in\operatorname{span}(u_2,\ldots,u_p)$, there are scalars $a_2,\ldots,a_p$ such that $u=a_2u_2+\cdots+a_pu_p$. For a similar reason, there are scalars $b_1,\ldots,b_{p-1}$ such that $u=b_1u_1+\cdots+b_{p-1}u_{p-1}$. But, since the $u_j$'s are linearly independent,$$a_2u_2+\cdots+a_pu_p=b_1u_1+\cdots+b_{p-1}u_{p-1}\implies a_p=b_1=0.$$Using this argument several times shows that all coefficients are $0$ and that therefore $u=0$.

Comment: I have given an answer which allows the possibility of $u\neq0$.

Comment: @PVanchinathan Your answer is wrong. You did not read the question properly.

Comment: Simple, elegant answer. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.